# Can I use the verb "constitutes" in this fashion?

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrases, expressions, verbs

For example: Being a member of the team constitutes to an amazing experience.

Would this be correct?

Comment: Avoid asking for help writing (or proofreading). “How should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, and “which is correct?” questions are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” ask that question instead. Also check out “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”

Answer (score 1):

You can if you remove the extra word "to".

I'm not sure why you'd prefer "constitutes" to "is" in that sentence, or a word that conveys some other meaning or flavor, such as "delivers".